# NXTcoin Startup - Error: Could not find or load main class nxt . Nxt

Tags: nxt

I setup a new VM with ubuntu 12.04 installed and installed java 8. I cloned the nxt repo and it is throwing this error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class nxt.Nxt**

What is this error and how can this be resolved?
thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first compile by doing:

```
./compile
```

then:

```
./run.sh
```